# Correct response when the only edit is to inline a hyperlink

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

I was reviewing an edit to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836468/on-jquery-how-to-manually-define-image-src-into-html-img-tag) in which the edit was to go from

> This is what i have so far, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwhLoyy8/1/

to

> This is what i have so far, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwhLoyy8/1/)

In this case i choose to reject the edit as

> This edit fails to make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

but was unsure, mainly I feel it was a superfluous edit but a small part of me saw that it could be trying to make the post easier to read.

would like to know what the community thinks on these situations and what the best course of action is next time.

Answer (score 1):

There are three points I would like to make from the point of view of an editor:

The first is that **every edit should actually make the post better**. When I edit, if the only thing I could change would to be make a link look nicer, I would not even bother. Edits are not suppose to be just a way to gain reputation. The only reason someone should edit is if the post has a problem.

If I could review those posts (I still have a loooong way to go), I would not accept edits that are obviously to just get reputation. If the editor is not willing to actually make the post better, the edit should not be approved.

**It would not hurt to approve the edit**. Although it is a minor edit, it does make the post look a little better. It would not hurt the post.

My third point is **reputation should not be dealt with so lightly**. Approving an edit should almost be treated as an upvote. You are rewarding them for their efforts to improve SO. In the same way you would not upvote an post that is not very good, you would not approve an edit. Why should a person who did not spend much time receive any amount of rep?

All of this should be taken in mind if approving an edit (in my opinion). In that case I would not approve the edit, because all that person is trying to do is to get two more rep.

Comment: I would reject this edit in specific, not because it is a minor edit but because it doesn't correct other *simple* issues with the post (IE, lowercase i's).  If that was the only thing that needed to be changed, it would be fine, but otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Pokechu22 my issue is does it need to be changed, even if it is the only thing does it really deserve the edit and as AHuman points out 2 rep is being given for what is a very trivial edit that does not add to the question. Is there a style guide for links on SO, is there a preferred route that the site wants to take?

Comment: @Quince Link formatting like that bothers me.  We've got markdown; it looks nicer when used.  If that were the only thing that needed to be changed in the post, I would accept it, but when there are other issues it is too minor.